# Flutter detect Http call status get response or failure

Tags: flutter

how i can detect http call status get response or failure
my call

```
http.post(Uri.encodeFull("http://172.20.10.3//Marketino/checkToken.php",), 
body: {"token":"$_token"})
```

i want detect if failure

Comment: Are you using dio package?

Comment: no only Http and i want detect failure

Answer (score 0):

> From server you get statuscode and acconding to statuscode you check
>   is get proper response or not

Here i use `then()` function so

```
 http.Response response =http.post(url,body: {"token":"$_token"});

 print("====response Body ${response.body.toString()}");
 print("====response StatusCode ${response.statusCode}");

  if (statusCode < 200 || statusCode >= 400 || json == null) {
    // call fail
  }else{
      // success
  }
```